# canActivate in 'authGuard' can't read ' observable current user ' of AuthServer

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I use angular2 rc.3 and @angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.7

my auth.server

```
export class AuthService {
  isLogged:boolean;
  constructor(private principal:PrincipalService){
  this.authenticated();
}
  authenticated() {
    this.principal.currentUser().subscribe(
      e=> {
        if (!!e && e.authenticated) {
          this.isLogged = true;
        }
        this.isLogged = false;
      },
    error=> {
      this.isLogged = false;
    }
    )
  }
```

AuthGuard:

```
constructor(private auth:AuthService )  {}
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean{ 
   // here the **auth.isLogged** is undefined !! why?**
    if(this.auth.isLogged){
      return true;
    }
     else {
      window.location.href='/login';
      return false;
    }
```

and I set the router

```
{
      path: 'property',
      component: PropertyHomeComponent,
      canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    }
```

when i open the '/property' page , the AuthGuard cannot read the **"this.auth.isLogged"** , and didn't redirect to the '/login' page ,

How to fix it ?

Comment: What do your files look like above their constructor? Their may be missing `@Injectable` decorators.

Comment: @Michael I have put `**@Injectable()**` in the head of **AuthService** and **AuthGuard**, and i did't found the error of **missing dependencies **

Comment: can you post a failing demo plunkr?

Comment: @Michael because my login page is on the back server . And use OAuth2,The condition for judging whether the login is successful is whether you can get the the current user from back .   Can i put a small front demo on github,I'm not familiar with plunkr

Answer (score 2):

I have found the revolution . (thank @Michael for his prompt）

**AuthGuard**

```
 return this.principal.currentUser().map(e=> {
      if (e) {
        return true;
      }
    }).catch(()=> {
      window.location.href = ConstantService.loginUrl;
      return Observable.of(false)
    })
  }
```

Comment: Won't `this.auth.isLogged()` always return `true` since you are directly comparing against the observable object instead of the value within it?

Comment: @Michael logic of **this.principalService.currentUser()** from back server is : if user logged in , it returns **current user**(contains: "id, roles,authenticated"...); Or because of 401, it will redirect to login page by back server,that also means front http error happens .  So `.catch(() => {
        console.log('not logged in !')
        return Observable.of(false)
      });`

Comment: @Kery Hu - Can you please post your full code. You only show sections of each file and I need to see entire code to get mine working. Where does `principal` come from, etc? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `isLogged` is not set by the time AuthGuard's `canActivate` method is trying to access it. This is because the setting of that variable is asynchronous.

Luckily, according to the [angular routing docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards)

> Accordingly, a routing guard can return an `Observable<boolean>` and the router will wait for the observable to resolve to `true` or `false`.

So in your case, you would change `isLogged` to an observable as follows:

```
import { AsyncSubject } from 'rxjs/AsyncSubject';
export class AuthService {
  isLogged: AsyncSubject<boolean> = new AsyncSubject();
  constructor(private principal:PrincipalService){
  this.authenticated();
}
  authenticated() {
    this.principal.currentUser().subscribe(
      e=> {
        if (!!e && e.authenticated) {
          this.isLogged.next(true);
        } else {
          this.isLogged.next(false);
        }
        this.isLogged.complete();
      },
      error=> {
        this.isLogged.next(false);
        this.isLogged.complete();
      }
    )
  }
```

You would then need to change AuthGuard's `canActivate` to return an observable:

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
  return this.auth.isLogged
    .do(
      isLoggedIn => { if(!isLoggedIn) this.router.navigate(['/login']) },
      error => console.error(error)
    );
```

The value of `isLogged` will be returned as an `Observable<boolean>`. The `do` method will navigate to the /login page if the observable resolves to `false`.

Let me know if this works. I'm not too familiar with rxjs (Observables) and the router.

Comment: First thanks ,I tried your suggests . there are two errors : **First** `isLogged:BehaviorSubject<boolean>=new BehaviorSubject();` reports error `TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`; and **second** `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'do' of undefined` ,

Comment: I set the init false in `BehaviorSubject<boolean>=new BehaviorSubject(**false**)`,above two error is missing .. But when i logged in . I can see `if (!!e && e.authenticated) {
          this.isLogged.next(true);
        }` **the param e.authenticated is 'true'** in **authService**, but the `.do(
      isLoggedIn => { if(!isLoggedIn) this.router.navigate(['/login']) },` **i can see the param isLoggedIn is 'false '**, and the Url redirected to unexpected **'/login'** page .. I am newer to Observables

Comment: I change  **this.principal.currentUser().subscribe(
      e=> {
        if (!!e && e.authenticated) {
          this.isLogged.next(true);
        }
        this.isLogged.next(false);
      },** to **this.principal.currentUser().subscribe(
      e=> {
        if (!!e && e.authenticated) {
          this.isLogged.next(false);
        }
        this.isLogged.next(true);
      },** ,  when logged in , `.do( isLoggedIn => { if(!isLoggedIn) this.router.navigate(['/login']) }`, ** the param isLoggedIn is still 'false '**, It seems isLogged' value didn't changed 
throughout the process

Comment: It seems Like BehaviorSubject requires an initial value, which we *don't* want because the guard will just use that value. Try using AsyncSubject (making sure to call complete in your principal.currentUser subscribe callbacks). I'll update the answer later when I have time.

Comment: @Michael you are the best. Thanks for this solution. Solved quite a lot of problems in our project.